# Mirror driver call to capture GDI Call

Tags: windows, driver, gdi, printers

I am working on sample which captures the GDI call and save it in some format. Once after saving I need to display back in some other application.

To Capture the GDI calls I hooked to GDI calls. This sample is a Available in DDK sample. I could Hook to GDI calls and I am getting the call to my DrvTextOut,  DrvBitBlt and etc calls.

My problem is how to save the calls and how to redraw it on the screen. Please let me know how to solve this problem.

Regards

Comment: May I kindly ask you to point me where is the sample to capture the GDI calls in the DDK ? Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an enhanced metafile
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162601(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162601%28VS.85%29.aspx)